# How to change tinyMCE editor's button's default tag output in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, xhtml, tinymce

Wordpress Tiny MCE editor and WP own editor both has button for `<blockquote>` . if we select any text and press this buttom then it wraps that text with `<blockquote>.....</blockquote>`.

I want to change this output to this

```
<blockquote><div class="quote_start"><div></div></div><div class="quote_end"><div></div></div>...................................</blockquote>
```

How can i do this manually or is there any wordpress plugin which can do the same?

I want to change behaviour of blockquote button in bot editor TinyMCE and WP own html editor?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can use this to add that many divs but tinymce's valid elements config parameter does allow you to replace tags.

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements

For instance:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements : "blockquote/div[class=quote_start]"
});
```

Would replace all blockquote tags with a div with the quote_start class.

A better way might be to ignore tinymce here and write a filter for the functions.php file of your theme. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content. Find all the instances of blockquote and replace it with the code you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding your own button could also be an option?

Some starting point could be this:

http://www.deliciousdays.com/tinymcebuttons/

and/or this:

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.Editor/addButton

hope it helps? Greetz, t..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same functionality in two different editors, you're probably better off writing (or looking for) a Wordpress filter that can replace the code. There's [**this one**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/text-replace/) but it doesn't seem to be able to handle regular expressions (which you would need to replace HTML tags). Maybe this one can do what you need: [**Text Filter Suite**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/text-filter-suite/)

Answer (score 0):

Getting both TinyMCE and Quicktags requires mods in two places.  Here's how to do the Quicktags: 
http://website-in-a-weekend.net/extending-wordpress/diy-wordpress-unraveling-quicktags-wordpress-plugins/